# DreamHost and CodeIgniter htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, dreamhost

I have a CodeIgniter application which is successfully deployed on localhost and justhost without any errors. Now, I need to migrate to DreamHost and place it in the subdirectory: http://mywebsite.com/code_igniter_root/ Now the applications give me the "No input file specified" error with this old htaccess file :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

When I change to this by adding the question mark after the RewriteRule index.php, it works:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

However, there is a problem that I cannot receive the post data anymore via $_POST and $this->input->post();

What is the solution for this problem? DreamHost is really annoying...

Comment: maybe some configuration in the [query string](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/urls.html)

Comment: If the url is going to be along the lines of `http://mywebsite.com/code_igniter_root/` make sure you have set the base url in the config/config.php file to `http://mywebsite.com/code_igniter_root/` . You may also need to alter your htaccess again to account for the subfolder. Something like `^(.*)$ code_igniter_root/index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]`.

Comment: Thank you, it is working now !
So non-www and www are different? How can I force the user into 1 version of non-www?

Comment: if you go to the www domain, it still doesn't work?

Comment: I don't think this should have been closed.  I think the title was poorly worded,  and @Jeemusu should have posted an answer rather than comment.  But it's a valid problem which I am experiencing as well.

Comment: I just came across this in case it helps anyone. It seems the question mark after the php is critical in the Dreamhost environment.   http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/55620/